# Trouble installing local python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble installing my project locally as a package. I have followed all instructions found [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), i.e. made sure all project subdirectories include an `__init__.py` file, set up a `setup.py` file in the top level of the project directory and installed with `pip install -e .`. However, when I try to import the package I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demopkg'`. Annoyingly, when I print the `sys.path` I see that the package path is included in the directory list.

The OS is macOS Mojave. I am using Conda 4.8.3 with Python 3.7

What could be going wrong?

Comment: do you mean `__init__.py` (with two underscores before and after "init", or did you use `init.py` like it says in your question? It should be the first one.

Comment: Sorry I did mean `__init__.py`. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you pip3 install demopkg it may work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I have source activated the relevant environment with conda anyway and it should default to pip3 I would imagine.